# Re: Transpose dynamic table - TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table created dynamically with dynamic columns. Column A, and Column B is static and rest of the columns are created dynamically based on results of another table. Consider the following sample code,

```
SELECT dutydate, dayname, shifts, myShift
    FROM   
       (SELECT column A, column B, dynamic column C, dynamic column D, dynamic column E, ...... (columns may increase)
           FROM temp) p
   UNPIVOT  
   (myShift FOR shifts IN ( dynamic column C, dynamic column D, dynamic column E, ...... (columns may increase) ))
AS unpvt;
```

temp table is dynamically created table. Is there a way to transpose based on the above scenario.

Comment: what do you mean by transpose?

Comment: I assume by 'transpose' he means 'normalise'.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing how you created the the table with the dynamic columns. What you could do is to create the command as a string with the list of columns and then just execute the string.

i.e.

```
declare @cmd varchar(max), @list_of_dynamic_columns varchar(255)
set @list_of_dynamic_columns = 'co1, col2, col2'

set @cmd = 'SELECT dutydate, dayname, shifts, myShift
    FROM   
       (SELECT column A, column B, '+@list_of_dynamic_columns +' 
           FROM temp) p
   UNPIVOT  
   (myShift FOR shifts IN ( '+@list_of_dynamic_columns +' ))
AS unpvt;'

print @cmd -- to see what you executed
exec (@cmd)
```

What you need to do is just create the list in the @list_of_dynamic_columns